# How to use Jackson to deserialize using sub types with a nullable property?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, jackson-databind

Context: I have two different JSON responses returned from an API. The first is the combined (movie & tv) crew credit information, and the second is **only** the tv crew credit information.

The first JSON specifies the property `media_type` which determines which class it should deserialize to. Below you can see it can either be `movie` or `tv`. For my outer model class `CombinedCredits`, this works.

The issue arises when I try to deserialize the second JSON, for the outer model class `TvCredits`. The JSON provided does **not** include a `media_type` property because it is expected to be for tv only.

I get the following error when trying to deserialize for `TvCredits`:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidTypeIdException: Could not resolve subtype of [simple type, class info.movito.themoviedbapi.model.people.TvCrew]: missing type id property 'media_type' (for POJO property 'crew')
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 25, column: 9] (through reference chain: info.movito.themoviedbapi.model.people.TvCredits["crew"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

I assume this is an issue with using the interface when the JSON does not have the expected deserialization property, but how else can I solve this without duplicating lots of code?

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "media_type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MovieCrew.class, name = "movie"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TvCrew.class, name = "tv")
})
public interface Crew {
    ...
}
```

```java
public class TvCrew implements Crew {
    ...
}
```

```java
public class MovieCrew implements Crew {
    ...
}
```

```java
public class CombinedCredits {
    private List<Crew> crew;

    ...
}
```

```java
public class TvCredits {
    private List<TvCrew> crew;

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `DEDUCTION` solves the issue. From the Jackson documentation:

> Alternatively, @JsonTypeInfo(use=DEDUCTION) can be used to avoid requiring the 'type' field. For deserialization, types are deduced based on the fields available. Exceptions will be raised if subtypes do not have a distinct signature of fieldnames or JSON does not resolve to single known signature.

```java
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.DEDUCTION)
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = MovieCrew.class, name = "movie"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = TvCrew.class, name = "tv")
})
public interface Crew {
    ...
}
```